# How to make port forwarding with UPNPNATClass

Tags: c#

I' trying to do port forwarding. I've done following:

NATUPNPLib.dll was added to references 
NATUPNPLib was added to using section of page
Following codes were written
But a null reference exception thrown

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using NATUPNPLib;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new UPnPNATClass();
            IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
            foreach (IStaticPortMapping map in mappings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(map.ExternalIPAddress);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: _"But a null reference exception thrown"_ Where? I guess on `upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;`?

Comment: Mesut please edit your question telling in which line you get the exception, or try to debug and check which object is null and what fails exactly.

Comment: The exception is thrown in just foreach code line.

Comment: mappings is null as the call to StaticPortMappingCollection failed and returned nothing